# Protractor tests hung up after finishing tests

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, protractor

I have configured grunt tasks to start the protractor webdriver and then run the protractor tests with protractor-runner, grunt config is like

```
    .....
    protractor_webdriver: {
        start: {
            options: {
                path: 'node_modules/protractor/bin/',
                command: 'webdriver-manager start --standalone'
            }
        }
    },
    protractor: {
        options: {
            configFile: proctatorConf,
            noColor: false,
            args: {
            }
        },
        auto: {
            options: {
                keepAlive: true,
                args: {
                }
            }
        },
        singlerun: {
            options: {
                keepAlive: false,
                args: {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ....
    grunt.registerTask('test:e2e', [
      'shell:update_webdriver',
      'protractor_webdriver:start',
      'protractor:singlerun'
    ]);
```

and in Jenkins i installed xvfb-plugin and said on the job configuration to startup Xvfb screen and shutdown after job finish,

And what is the problem is that when jenkins execute `grunt test:e2e` command, it executes all test, give me failure information like

`Finished in 16.455 seconds
[31m4 tests, 6 assertions, 4 failures`

and jenkins job hungs on that, what could be the problem for this?

Comment: it's such a long chain of processes so it's impossible to debug. but first question I have in mind - does it run as expected locally without `Xvfb` etc?